# Following up a Question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope, specific-question

I was highly impressed by @TildalWave 's [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37686/is-there-any-way-to-tell-if-cctv-is-on-or-not#37687) and so I wanted to follow up on @D3C4FF 's [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37686/is-there-any-way-to-tell-if-cctv-is-on-or-not) and ask how physical cameras (CCTV/IP) can be disabled.

My questions here are:
1 - Is following up like this appropriate?
2 - Is my question on disabling cameras on-topic/appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly ask follow up questions. The usually accepted technique is to write your question and just refer to the earlier question with a link and a summary.

I also think your follow up is on topic - we do try and focus on the relationship between attack route and defence strategy, but both ends of the discussion are relevant here.

Comment: ♦ as usual, you are very kind; thanks.